# Overlaying data on an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two plots I want to overlay on top of each other as shown in the link below:

[image]

The inputs are the two images on the left and the output is the image on the right. Here's the code I used:

```
reference = imread('ref_foam.png');
figure, imshow(reference);
hold on;
h = imshow(data,[]);
hold off
colormap jet;
alphamap = zeros(size(reference,1),size(reference,2));
for i = 0:size(data,1)-1
    for j = 0:size(data,2)-1
        if(~(data(i+1,j+1) == 0))
             alphamap(i+1,j+1) = 0.75;
        end            
    end
end
set(h, 'AlphaData', alphamap);
```

Anytime there's a zero in the data array, it sets that transparency to zero or else it will set the transparency to 0.75.

Now, my questions are: How can I get the colormap to apply to only the data array? In this example it works but if I convert "reference" to a grayscale, the colormap applies to that as well. The input for the colormap is an axes handle, is there anyway to input the image's handle (h) so that it only applies to the top (data) array? Also, I'd like to implement a colorbar as well. Is there anyway to apply the colorbar only to the data array? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `subimage` command - it lets you create images on the same figure with different colormaps.

Once create and modified as in your script, overlay the images by setting their axes positions on top of each other.